# Google Workflows: RecursionError: recursion depth limit reached: 10

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-workflows

I have a hierarchy of a workflow calling a subworkflow which is calling another subworkflow etc.

When I called a specific subworkflow at upper level I did not get the `RecursionError`. Calling the same subworkflow at lower level in the hierarchy caused the error.

Although I read the doc of this error ([RecursionError](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/errors/recursion_error)), I cannot see in which case, this error can occur. Especially it's raised when detected by the interpreter and not at runtime.

I took a look at quotas and limits but I cannot see any limitation on workflows hierarchy depth.

PS: I'm quite sure the call I'm making is not causing stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you can add your subworkflows in another workflow and call it with an [experimental.execution.run](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/run) type. I wrote [a article where I use it](https://medium.com/google-cloud/parallel-executions-with-google-workflows-3a16f8fee0eb)

*PS: documentation is very young, and absolutely not perfect. It's maybe for this that you don't see this limit.*

Comment: Thx for your feedback ! So you do confirm there is a hard limit of 10 on the call hierarchy depth?

Comment: I confirm that I have the same limitation on my side. i don't know if it's a hard limit, and if, in the future, it will be increased.

Comment: Unless I missed smth it did not solve my problem: I have a workflow with a deep subworkflows hierarchy that is working (no RecursionError). I started putting subworkflows in standalone workflows and calling them using `experimental.executions.run` unfortunately it raises the RecursionError albeit it did not in the initial workflow :( Any idea ! thx again !

Comment: Could you please share your a snippet of  your implementation?